# Can I place citations in captions using Tufte?

Tags: bibliographies, captions, citing, natbib, tufte

I'm trying to get Tufte marginal material (citations, footnotes, and captions) to support incorporate citations as they do in the Tufte books. What I'm looking for is the "conversational" style that's used in Tufte's books in, for example, notes 36 and 38 on p.70 of *[Visual Explanations](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_visex)*:

[image: Examples from Tufte of footnotes containing citations]

These should be generated from something like the following code:

```
\footnote{\cite{Tooley,Leighly,McLaughlin} The map shown is\cite{Jassonius}, a reissue of\cite{Hondius}, in \cite{Hondius1631} as reproduced in Leighly, plate v. Redrawn.}

\footnote{At far left, \cite{Green}, p. 128, showing an error by the well-known illustrator, Edward Mishell. The extra finger is not needed in performing the manipulation. Unnotced for years, the slip was spotted by Richard Kaufman, who then drew a homage to Mishell's sixth finger--at lear left,\cite{Kaufman}, p. 260.}
```

Note the same should also apply to `\cite` within captions, as illustrated on the right in the figure above. Note also that (not shown above) initial citations always appear as full entires, while subsequent ones appear abbreviated, regardless of whether the initial citation was in a simple `\cite` or in a footnote (even the same footnote).

I've [been experimenting with a bibtex-based solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46012/7844), but (in addition to having some bugs) it generates errors for any attempts to put basic citations in figure captions.

For for example, something like the following

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This is some text to attach to a figure.
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{...}
\caption{Here is some caption text, and here 
  (\cite{...}) is a citation within that text. }
\end{marginfigure}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

generates these errors and halts:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

Substituting `\citep` for `\cite` runs error-free and produces the expected output (but of, course, does not work for full, initial citations; `\bibentry` produces even more errors).

Comment: Weird! I'm guessing this is a question of curiosity though, since `citet` and `citep` etc. should do the job just as well. I'll be interested to see the outcome of this.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Partly curiosity (since [I'm hoping for a comprehensive solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46012/7844)) but also because without it I'm stuck. I need to be able to just `cite` and have the right thing happen, without having to hand code each citation. Also, as noted, there's no way to get this to work for a first occurrence, since `\bibentry\ fails too.

Comment: I agree, a robust solution would be better. I'm a tad confused though, is your desire to use `cite` because you're copying and pasting a lot of code, or using auto-completes or something?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: To preserve markup semantics. But, yes, you're right on both guesses. One of the consequences of getting the semantics right is, indeed, that material can be moved around freely and the code sorts out how to render it. Another is that the act of "citing" is simpler (e.g. for me, just use the "Insert Citation" command in LyX, which is a form of "autocomplete" in a sense).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: The error occurs by the command `\@tufte@sidenote` related to `\sidenote`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks. FWIW, I've found this is a lot easier to do (it works with very little code) using biblatex, so I've switched to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be made to work easily using `biblatex`. Simply replace *one* of the citation commands, e.g.:

```
\let\citep\footcite
```

and load `biblatex` with the options

```
citestyle=verbose
citecounter=true
citetracker=true
```

and `\citep` alone will generate sidenotes, while all others will behave as needed in footnotes and captions (including abbreviating automatically as required). Then

```
\footnote{\citealt{Tooley,Leighly,McLaughlin} The map shown is\citealt{Jassonius}, a reissue of\citealt{Hondius}, in \citealt{Hondius1631} as reproduced in Leighly, plate v. Redrawn.}

\footnote{At far left, \citealt{Green}, p. 128, showing an error by the well-known illustrator, Edward Mishell. The extra finger is not needed in performing the manipulation. Unnotced for years, the slip was spotted by Richard Kaufman, who then drew a homage to Mishell's sixth finger--at lear left,\citealt{Kaufman}, p. 260.}
```

will produce exactly the output sought (while using `\citep` in main text can still be used to generate "regular" footnote citations).

Comment: Remember to replace `\bibliogaphy` with `\addbibresource` as part of the switch to biblatex.