# Shortening margin citations in tufte class

Tags: bibliographies, tufte

How would one display just the Author and Year of the citation in the margin, while keeping the full citation in the references page?

I've tried to modify a [previous suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45868/can-i-automatically-generate-abbreviated-citations-in-tufte-documents-after-the/45878#45878) that would display abbreviated citations only after they had be cited once. This unfortunately didn't work -- the reference number appears instead of any citation at all:

[image]

This is what they usually look like:

[image]

As you can see it gets very busy very quickly. Some pages the margin is all citations!

I've searched everywhere for this and tried editing solutions to similar requests -- alas! No luck. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nofonts,oneside]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
%------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Non-equilibrium Spin Mixing}

Spontaneous Magnetization!! \cite{lamport94}

Under the constraint of number and magnetization conservation, there are just two dynamical variables\cite{lamport94}: $\rho_0$, the fractional population of the $m=0$ component, and     relative phase difference $\theta (t)\equiv\theta_+ + \theta_- - 2\theta_0$. $\theta$ can     be thought of as a control for the degree of magnetization.

Under the SMA, the spin-dependent energy functional is given by\cite{lamport94}:

    \begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've included a minimal working example.

Comment: Your MWE is not compilable...

Answer (score 2):

Your MWE is not compilable, but you can try the following: Use `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`. You can find the explanation how to do that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45949/8631).  Then, you can take advantage of biblatex's large set of options. Put

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}
```

in the preamble to not show the title in the margin. However, the bibliography will still show it.

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}
```

clears the `url` as well and so on. Biblatex even allows different citation and bibliography styles. I strongly recommend it with `tufte-latex`.

Comment: I cleared all the fields I could think of, but I still get a margin note citation of the form `Author. In: (Year)`. Any idea how to get rid of the `In:` and the dots after author and year?